# Spring ObjectError getDefaultMessage() encoding

Tags: java, spring, encoding

I am using @Valid annotation and the when error mesage has special characters they are always being  displayed incorrectly.

```
public class Test {
 @NotEmpty(message = "{test}")
 private String test;
 //omitted getter and setter
}
```

ValidationMessages.properties:

```
test=Número
```

Error Handling:

```
private void handleBindException(final Exception ex, final Result res) {
    BindException bex = (BindException) ex;
    for (ObjectError error : bex.getAllErrors()) {
        res.addError(new ErrorCode(error.getCode(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
    }
}
```

Spring MessageResouce:

```
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ms = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ms.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
        ms.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        ms.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        ms.setCacheSeconds(0);
        return ms;
    }
```

Final result:

```
NÃºmero
```

Can anybody help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `ValidationMessages.properties` is `UTF-8` encoded. Use a text editor (e.g. Notepad++) or the IDE to change the encoding.